# Swift 4 CGRect height cannot be used

Tags: swift, cgrect

I am using swift 4 & getting the following error:

> Instance member 'height' cannot be used on type 'CGRect'

When using the below code:

```
 let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

let changeInHeight = (CGRect.height(keyboardFrame) + 40) * (show ? 1 : -1)
```

I cannot figure out why, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height` is a property of a `CGRect` structure. You are accessing it like it is a class method. Since `keyboardFrame` is of type `CGRect`, you want `keyboardFrame.height` instead.

```
let changeInHeight = (keyboardFrame.height + 40) * (show ? 1 : -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval

        let changeInHeight = (keyboardFrame.height + 40) * (show ? 1 : -1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDurarion, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.bottomConstraint.constant += changeInHeight
        })
```